# Fundamental solution of the Poisson equation with variable exponent

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, potential-theory, reference-works

Let the variable exponent $p(x)$, where $p(x) \in C(\overline{\Omega})$, I want to know the fundamental solution of 
$$-(\Delta u)^{p(x)}=\delta_0.$$

Comment: I don't think there is any closed form for that, or really anything with a variable exponent. Also, the nonlinearity of the equation limits the use of its fundamental solution.

Comment: there is reference of potential theory of this type of equation?

Comment: Is there some motivation for this question that might help in formulating an answer, or at least a reference for a possible answer?